# Dimension mismatch: array 'cov' is of shape (1, 1), but 'mean' is a vector of length 2

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, kalman-filter

I'm trying to execute the following code

```
p, c = [], []
for z in mes:
    print (z)
    print (c)
    print (p)
    p.append(kf.x)
    c.append(kf.P)
    kf.predict()
    kf.update(z) #error on this line
```

I get the error :

> ValueError: Dimension mismatch: array 'cov' is of shape (1, 1), but
>   'mean' is a vector of length 2.

This is the ouput that shows on the screen

```
[512  102]
[array([[ 1000.,     0.,     0.,     0.],
       [    0.,  1000.,     0.,     0.],
       [    0.,     0.,  1000.,     0.],
       [    0.,     0.,     0.,  1000.]])]
[array([[ 396.],
       [  187.],
       [    0.],
       [    0.]])]
```

It works fine if I only take the first element of `z`, however, that isn't the behavior I desire.

```
p, c = [], []
for z in mes:
    print (z)
    print (c)
    print (p)
    p.append(kf.x)
    c.append(kf.P)
    kf.predict()
    kf.update(z[0])
```

**Update additional info**

This error is coming from [`multivariate.py` in scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L396). I can't seem to be able to change the shape of `cov` from `(1,1)`. I can change the length of `mean` by using `z[0]`, however, that isn't desired. I would like to use `z` as is. I've also posted the entire code as a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/Omnipresent/1aeb08f88d10af3c5e3d#file-myprog-py-L107). I'm also utilizing the [filterpy library](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python) for the Kalman filter. There is a [live python notebook](http://app.mybinder.org/2665079991/notebooks/06-Multivariate-Kalman-Filters.ipynb) using this kalman filter, however, it isn't using the `z` as in my scenario.

Comment: can you include the code (or dummy code) defining `kf` and `mes`? I can't work out what your code's trying to go.

Comment: The error itself is straightforward: somewhere in the implementation of `kf.update()` there's some operation involving a variable called `c` and a variable called `mean` (which I'm guessing is the argument to `kf.update()`), the dimensions of which need to be compatible for the operation to work. Probably a matrix multiplication. But I can't say much more than that, in particular how to fix it, without at least knowing which Kalman filter implementation you're using. Having a high-level description of what you're trying to do would be handy too.

Comment: @maxymoo I've posted the entire code as a gist here https://gist.github.com/Omnipresent/1aeb08f88d10af3c5e3d#file-myprog-py-L107 I'm using kalman filters from this library https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python

Comment: @DavidZ I'm using github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python to implement kalman filters. Also I added the gist of the code https://gist.github.com/Omnipresent/1aeb08f88d10af3c5e3d#file-myprog-py-L107 You are correct. But I can't seem to figure out how to update `cov` such that it isn't `(1,1)`. I think If I can change that ...everything would work. `mean` is of length 2 but I want to keep it that way. like I mentioned, If i change length of it to 1 (`z[0]`) everything works fine.

Comment: @Anthony OK, that helps. But let me recommend editing the content of these comments into the question. It's important information to have even after the comments are deleted, if they are deleted.

Comment: Actually, your code is not _quite_ complete because it requires an input file. I suppose you could edit a link to a sample input (which displays the problem) into the question. Alternatively you could develop a shorter program which is self-contained and also displays the problem. I'll look into it anyway; perhaps, now that I know which filter implementation you're using, I can offer something useful.

Comment: @DavidZ I added the the first five records from the input text file. It should demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96251/discussion-between-david-z-and-anthony).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the filterpy library you're responsible for setting up the initial state of the Kalman filter yourself, and the dimensions of the various matrices need to be compatible. If you look into the `KalmanFilter.update()` method, you can track the computations it does and come up with the following set of constraints on the matrix dimensions:

```
R.shape == (dim_z, dim_z)
H.shape == (dim_z, dim_x)
P.shape == (dim_x, dim_x)
x.shape == (dim_x, 1...)
z.shape == (dim_z, 1...)
```

where the `1...` can represent some sequence of dimensions of size 1 which is the same for both. For example, in your case, `dim_x == 4` and `dim_z == 2` so you could have `x.shape == (4, 1)` and `z.shape == (2, 1)`, or you could have `x.shape == (4,)` and `z.shape == (2,)`, but you can't mix and match. (Note that the `KalmanFilter.__init__()` documentation appears to give the wrong required dimensions for `H`.)

Your code sets the wrong dimensions in two places:

- You set `H` to be a 1x4 matrix instead of 2x4 as it should be. (I notice here you've got valid code commented out.)
- You set `R` to be a scalar value instead of a 2x2 matrix. Arguably the Kalman filter implementation should account for this, but it only does so when you pass `R` as a parameter to `update()`, not when you set it in advance. (Be careful though: the code will still *work* if you set `R` to be a scalar! It'll do what I believe to be the wrong thing, though: adding 2 to every element of a matrix instead of adding 2 times the identity matrix.)
- When you pass `z` to the `update()` method, you're passing a two-element list which gets converted into a 2-element vector, not a 2x1 matrix as it should be to be compatible with `x` (which is 4x1). You *can* fix this by running `z = np.array([z]).T` in the body of the loop before calling `update()`. But I think there's a better way: leave `z` as it is, and just make `x` a 4-element vector:

  ```
  x = np.array([measurements[0][0],measurements[0][1],0.,0.])
  ```

  I'm not sure if this is meant to work by the author, but it does (at the moment), and it probably should. I think it's sort of silly to require converting each measurement to a 2x1 matrix before passing it in.

`KalmanFilter` includes a `test_matrix_dimensions()` method which you can use to check for errors in your setup. But I'm sort of ambivalent about it because if you set `x` to be a 4-element vector, as I suggested in the last paragraph, it will flag that as incorrect.